# Deploying Maven project via GitHub actions fails

Tags: maven, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy a multi module project to GitHub packages but whenever Maven hits the "deploy" cycle it fails.

my GitHub action job:

```yaml
  release:
    name: Release 
    # needs: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      actions: write
      repository-projects: write
      packages: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: master
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 17
          distribution: adopt
          cache: maven
      - name: Release package
        run: |
          git config user.name "githubaction[bot]"
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          mvn -B release:prepare
          mvn -B release:perform
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

My pom files has the needed config:

```xml
  <distributionManagement>
    <!-- Github distribution -->
    <repository>
      <id>github</id>
      <name>GitHub Packages</name>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/MYUSERNAME/${project.artifactId}</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/${project.artifactId}</developerConnection>
  </scm>
```

The prepare step goes fine but a soon as Maven tries to perform the release (and thus hits the deploy stage) I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-artifact-sub-module: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact my-artifact-sub-module:jar:1.1.0 in github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/mathiasbosman/fs-core) -> [Help 1]
```

Which is bizar as right before it fails Maven logs:

```
[INFO] Uploading to github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/my/path/my-artifact-sub-module/1.1.0/my-artifact-sub-module-1.1.0.jar
[INFO] Uploading to github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/my/path/my-artifact-sub-module/1.1.0/my-artifact-sub-module-1.1.0.pom
```

The structure would be:

```
my-artifact (pom)
- my-artifact-sub-module (jar)
- my-artifact-sub-module-two (jar)
```

I tried calling mvn deploy manually in a seperate step but it gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scm url apperently was wrong (missing the .git extension)
As simple as that.

The complete scm:

```xml
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:${project.scm.url}</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:${project.scm.url}</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/${project.artifactId}.git</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>
```